# Spring Security: Upgrading the deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in Spring Boot 2.7.5

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to update my application without the use of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and I need help. The code is before and after the changes. I don't know for sure about the authenticationManager. I used multiple website to refactor my code.

Before:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private CustomPasswordEncoder customPasswordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;


    @Override @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(customPasswordEncoder
                        .getPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http = http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        // Set session management to stateless
        http = http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and();

        // Set unauthorized requests exception handler
        http = http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(
                        (request, response, ex) -> {
                            response.sendError(
                                    HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                                    ex.getMessage()
                            );
                        }
                )
                .and();

        // Set permissions on endpoints
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();


        // Add JWT token filter
        http.addFilterBefore(
                jwtFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
        );

    }

}
```

After refactoring my code without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private CustomPasswordEncoder customPasswordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;



    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        return builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(customPasswordEncoder.getPasswordEncoder())
                .and().build();
    }



    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http = http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        // Set session management to stateless
        http = http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and();

        // Set unauthorized requests exception handler
        http = http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(
                        (request, response, ex) -> {
                            response.sendError(
                                    HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                                    ex.getMessage()
                            );
                        }
                )
                .and();

        // Set permissions on endpoints
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();


        // Add JWT token filter
        http.addFilterBefore(
                jwtFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
        );

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

And Lastly this is my AuthController. After performing the changes in my SecurityConfig the Application stops working. With a huge error.
"org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$SecurityFilterChainConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'defaultSecurityFilterChain' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration.httpSecurity' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity]: Factory method 'httpSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer@53da2aec to already built object"

```
package io.qbeat.tmregistrationtool.web;

import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import io.qbeat.tmregistrationtool.domain.User;
import io.qbeat.tmregistrationtool.dto.AuthCredentialsRequest;
import io.qbeat.tmregistrationtool.util.JwtUtil;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseCookie;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    private String domain;
    @PostMapping("login")
    public ResponseEntity <?> login (@RequestBody AuthCredentialsRequest request){
        try {
            Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager
                    .authenticate(
                            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                    request.getUsername(), request.getPassword()
                            )
                    );

            User user = (User) authenticate.getPrincipal();
            user.setPassword(null);
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .header(
                            HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
                            jwtUtil.generateToken(user)
                    )
                    .body(user);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException ex) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/validate")
    public ResponseEntity<?> validateToken(@RequestParam String token,
                                           @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
        try {
            Boolean isValidToken = jwtUtil.validateToken(token, user);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(isValidToken);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what is the problem that you are facing

Comment: Sorry my bad I forgot to add the erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to fix my issue. The issue was with the AuthenticationManager.

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(customPasswordEncoder.getPasswordEncoder());
    return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
}
```